# How to fix d3-zoom doesn't work after pipeline

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, pipeline

I am using d3@5.16.0 to draw a graph in Vue.

It works well when I develop it on localhost or build it on local machine.
When I push the code on GitLab and start run pipeline ,the graph fail to zoom an throw error like:

```
Cannot read property 'ctrlKey' of null
```

I figure out that the event is null. How can I fix it without upgrading the version? Otherwise it may lead to many changes in my project.

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import {event} from 'd3';

//method content
var svgDOM = d3.select('#presuc')
var svg = svgDOM.append('g');
function zoomActions () {
    svg.attr('transform', event.transform)
}

let zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1 / 8, 1.5]).on("zoom",zoomActions);
zoom(svgDOM);
```

Comment: It looks like you have V6 in GitLab. I suggest to move your code to V6

Comment: Do you mean d3.v6? I checked  that I have v5 in the git lab

Comment: `ctrlKey` is a property of an event. If you use V5 and `d3.event` and then upgrade to V6, it will produce an error. If it's still V5, there should be another problem. Please post the code that generates the error